# Image color recognition, the general color

Tags: python, ruby

I want to get the most prominent color of an image, and the language can be in either python or ruby.

Is this easily done?

Comment: You need to supply more details: what is a "prominent color"? Are you looking for a general category ("red-ish"), or an exact value (`rgba(243,32,17)`)? What about pixels that are very similar in color value or hue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you mean, but maybe it will be helpful:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

image = Image.read("stack.png")[0]
hash = image.color_histogram
color, number = hash.max{|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
puts color.to_color
```

This worked like a charm for very simple image (only 5 colors), but should work for more complex images too (I did not tested that; returned hash will be quite big in that case, so you might want to use quantize on your image before using color_histogram).

Some resources :

[color_histogram](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#color_histogram)
[quantize](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#quantize)

I hope this was useful to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but the Python PIL has im.histogram() and im.getcolors() functions. http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Answer (score 1):

OK. Let me introduce the library for Ruby.

Using Camellia, http://camellia.sourceforge.net/examples.html, you can label the area with the most prominent color.