# Are there any color recognition libraries built in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, colors

I am trying to integrate a color recognition tool that identifies the overriding color  of an image and labels/tags the image based on the hex code of that color.

Comment: Would really help if you could discuss file formats of the image, and state that all pixels if the image are the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

image = Image.read("stack.png")[0]
hash = image.color_histogram
color, number = hash.max{|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
puts color.to_color
```

This is a similar question

[Image color recognition, the general color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911066/image-color-recognition-the-general-color)